# Vue is not defined with cordova/framework7/vue

Tags: cordova, vue.js, html-framework-7

Followed the tutorial here: 
http://blog.toast38coza.me/building-a-mobile-app-with-vuejs-cordova-webpack-and-framework-7/

and have created an app that works great.  however, when I added a plugin:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/index.html#properties

and followed this to access it:
http://kartsims.github.io/vue-cordova/#documentationtroubleshooting

I just get Vue is undefined.

Comment: You should probably create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We're not going to follow those tutorials for you to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: unfortunately, it's no trivial thing as there are many many files with this setup, somebody that is familiar with using Vue with Cordova and Framework 7 will need to answer, this is a specific problem with how framework7, vue and cordova are set up.   Somehow, the global variables are not being found in the vue file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be something silly and simple.  cordova.js is not implemented in the entire project, you still have to add it.  add it to your index.html and your plugins should work.